# How to select printer paper tray

Tags: c#, printing, printers

I have hp lbp 2900 printer with two paper tray. When trying

```
 int i = printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSources.Count;
```

It gives 1 only, why not two?? Is there any alternate solution to select paper tray. In c#.

Comment: Are you sure it gives paper sources from selected printer?